# Bounce content of UIScrollView back to edges in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I created a `UIScrollView` for SwiftUI as follows:

**ScrollView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ZoomableScrollView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    private var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        // set up the UIScrollView
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator  // for viewForZooming(in:)
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
        
        // Indicators
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        // create a UIHostingController to hold our SwiftUI content
        let hostedView = context.coordinator.hostingController.view!
        hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        hostedView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        hostedView.frame = scrollView.bounds
        scrollView.addSubview(hostedView)
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(hostingController: UIHostingController(rootView: self.content))
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        // update the hosting controller's SwiftUI content
        context.coordinator.hostingController.rootView = self.content
        assert(context.coordinator.hostingController.view.superview == uiView)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Coordinator
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>
        
        init(hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>) {
            self.hostingController = hostingController
        }
        
        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return hostingController.view
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZoomableScrollView {
               Rectangle()
                  .foregroundColor(.blue)
                  .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want the content of the `UIScrollView` to bounce back to the edge when dragged off the screen.

I've found several tutorials on how to do this with a `UIImage`, however I don't know how to apply this to my code.

Comment: Instead of going this way, I combined a SwiftUI `ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {}` and a `MagnificationGesture()`. This works very well and is SwiftUI native.